# Entity Framework 5 - T4 generated context class causing 'duplicate parameter name'

Tags: linq-to-sql, entity-framework-5, user-defined-functions, t4

I'm using EF5.0 in an ASP.NET MVC app. My Entity Model is named 'DataModel'. Included in the model is a table-valued function that exists in my MSSQL database, named MatchingEntries. It returns a table of integer ids.

I've looked at the DataModel.Context.cs file, that gets generated via the .tt (T4) template file. It has the following code in it:

```
[EdmFunction("DataEntities", "MatchingEntries")]
public virtual IQueryable<Nullable<int>> MatchingEntries(string term)
{
    var termParameter = term != null ?
        new ObjectParameter("Term", term) :
        new ObjectParameter("Term", typeof(string));

    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CreateQuery<Nullable<int>>("[DataEntities].[MatchingEntries](@Term)", termParameter);
}
```

The error I am getting results from using this method twice within the one query, such as:

```
IQueryable<int> one = db.MatchingEntries("\"one*\"");
IQueryable<int> two = db.MatchingEntries("\"two*\"");
List<int> both = one.Intersect(two).ToList();
```

The error is:

```
A parameter named 'Term' already exists in the parameter collection. Parameter names must be unique in the parameter collection.
Parameter name: parameter
```

Is this a known limitation of the classes generated from an EDMX for table-valued functions? With LINQ2SQL I am able to execute this a a single query to the database (that does a JOIN between the 2 outputs from MatchingEntries) and it replaces the parameter name @Term with @p0 and @p1 for the two different instances of the call. I'd like to make Entity Framework do the same.

So, my question is, how can I get EF to work in the same manner and avoid the 'Duplicate parameter' error?

My fallback is to evaluate each call to db.MatchingEntries separately, by putting ToList() after them. My other idea has been to replace the ObjectParameter name in the T4 generated Context.cs class with something randomly generated each time. These feel like hacks that I should be able to avoid.

Comment: I am trying to achieve the same than you. I also created a user defined function for a fulltext search. How did you resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is Linq to Entities specific. This doesn't have to be done in Linq to SQL (Linqpad).

Thanks to this question I got a pointer to a viable solution:

- extend the autogenerated DBContext class (partial class)
- add a method with two parameters in the partial class
- at calling, pass an index as second parameter

Detailed Answer:

DataEntitys.my.cs:

```
[EdmFunction("DataEntities", "MatchingEntries")]
public virtual IQueryable<Nullable<int>> MatchingEntries(string term, int index)
{

    string param_name = String.Format("k_{0}", index);

    var termParameter = term != null ?
        new ObjectParameter(param_name, term) :
        new ObjectParameter(param_name, typeof(string));

    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).
    ObjectContext.CreateQuery<Nullable<int>>(
    String.Format("[DataEntities].[MatchingEntries](@{0})", param_name), 
    termParameter);
}
```

Call the function:

```
foreach (string teil in such)
{
     index++;
     if (teil.Trim() != "")
         res = res.Join(db.MatchingEntries("\"" + teil + "*\"", index), l => l.ID, s => s.KEY, (l, s) => l);

}
```